# Mavericks: Can't be logged into two servers at the same time?

Tags: macos, network, finder, file-sharing, smb

I ran into a bug (or feature) in OS X 10.9 that I can't figure out.

If I'm trying to log into two servers, and I use "guest" credentials to log into one of them, things get screwy.

Example:

1. Connect to Server1 (smb://server1) as a "Guest." Select share. Works great.
2. Connect to Server2 (smb://server2). Finder does not give me the option to log in. Instead, it shows a box with a list of shares on the server. When I try to connect to a share, I get an error saying I do not have the right permissions.

The reason? I'm apparently also logged in as GUEST to server2. Check it out:

[image: screenshot]

In most cases, I can't disconnect from the server, regardless of how many times I click the button. I have to restart the system instead.

This is not a problem in OS X 10.6.8, nor in 10.10. I've also tried connecting via SMB1 (using CIFS, and by [forcing SMB1](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20131122083837447) at the account level). I'm at a loss as how to fix this from the client end. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the share using command-K and then using smb://DOMAIN;User@ServerName/ShareName ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, bmike. Yes, I still get the permissions error. Also, I've tried using CIFS instead of SMB, and forcing SMB1 instead of SMB2.

Comment: @ericbakes are server1 & server2 member of an AD?

Comment: @klanomath, server02 is a member of an AD. server01 is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I had to disable the Guest account on SERVER2. The guest account didn't have access to any shares, but it seems that simply having it active was enough to cause a problem. Here's what I think happened: 1) Log into server1 as "GUEST". 2) Log into server2. OS X must cache network credentials, so tried "GUEST." 3) Server responded with a list of shares, but since GUEST didn't have access, returned permissions error when I tried to open a share. Still seems buggy to me. If anyone has additional insight, feel free to post here.